# Why does the Google Chrome .exe file I downloaded not work on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome

Why is the Google Chrome browser not available on Ubuntu? I have tried by downloading the .exe file and it did not work.

Comment: It is, and has long been available for Ubuntu. You need to select the Debian/Ubuntu installation. Help can be found at https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95346?hl=en under "Linux"

Comment: The reason it doesn't run is because `.exe` files are designed for Windows, and won't run on Ubuntu without using Wine or a VM. So get the Linux version. Your

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clarification : This `.exe` file you downloaded is an installation file for Windows operating systems. You can install Google Chrome in Ubuntu this way, open a terminal and execute these commands:

```
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

In case that you are receiving an `apt update` error, please read this information on Ask Ubuntu ->
[No more updates for Google Chrome | apt-get update error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error/724170#724170)

Comment: `apt` provides an `update` command too... since you are already using `apt` for `install` why not for `update`?

Comment: @Bakuriu I made an edit to change it to that, it's now up for peer review.

Comment: You should clarify the difference between Windows and Ubuntu regarding exe files.

Answer (score 5):

Because chrome is not open source. Ubuntu (as most other Linux distributions) come with chromium instead, which is the open source project that chrome is based on.

Because chrome isn't open and re-distributable, it can include some things that aren't really free but typically aren't hard to get (if you want them), I've read that in ubuntu (I use Debian) you can install

```
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: But Google Chrome _is_ available on Ubuntu.

Comment: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra conflicts with chromium-codecs-ffmpeg.  It seems to be choose-one situation, where the -extra package provides everything the non-extra did and more, since my Chromium works fine with video / audio.

Answer (score 4):

You can go on the Google website and download the .deb package from this url : https://www.google.fr/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

The google website will auto-detect you're operating system here GNU/Linux, if not click on other platform and select "Linux" if will give you two options an RPM and a DEB package, as you run Ubuntu, you will choose the "64 bit .deb (For Debian/Ubuntu)" package.

Once downloaded you just have to run the command

```
sudo dpkg --install /path/to/package.deb
```

If will say that it miss some dependencies which you can fix by running this command

```
sudo apt-get install --force
sudo dpkg --install /path/to/package.deb
```

(Thanks cas for the reminder :))

Comment: you don't install a .deb **file** with `apt-get install`.  Use `dpkg -i` for files, `apt-get install` for package **names** stored in and known by as repo (i.e. in a Packages or Packages.gz, Packages.bz2, etc list file).

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't run is because `.exe` files are designed for Windows, and won't run on Ubuntu without using Wine or a VM. So you downloaded the wrong file. You need to get the Linux version. You're looking for the file that ends with `.deb`.

[Here is a link to the file you need.](https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb)

Please note that this will only work if you have a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, as 32-bit is no longer supported by Google.

If you have a 32-bit version of Ubuntu, I'll advise you to use Chromium, Firefox or Midori instead.